# Check if MatSidenav closing animation ended

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

How can I check if the MatSidenav component finished its closing animation? I'm looking at the documentation but I can only see a closedStart event. Is there some workaround or something I am missing for what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I can use the openedChange event which is triggered when the opening or closing animation is fully complete.

Answer (score 0):

Since the animation duration is .5s you can store the time at which it starts closing and know anytime if the animation is finished by doing:

`let finished = (Date.now() - timeStarted) > 500;`